# Unresolved reference: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a beginner and using Kotlin to develop my app. I was following a tutorial and when I tried to seek permissions following line of the code started giving an error of `Unresolved reference: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

I have already added following in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Try `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved. I used wrong import for Manifest. Correct import is
import android.Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Let x.y.z = packageName

I added
import android.Manifest
after removing
import x.y.z.Manifest